# What is "potential" in the context of a conducting liquid bubble that collapses into a droplet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

> A conducting liquid bubble of radius $a$ and thickness $t$ $\left(t \ll a\right)$ is charged to a potential $V$. If the bubble collapses to a droplet, find the potential energy on the droplet.

**Questions:**

1. In order to solve the above problem, is it necessary to consider self potential energies of the bubble and the droplet?
2. What exactly does "*potential*" mean in the above problem?

Comment: That is confusing. It is not clear whether they mean voltage or energy. Has your course covered how much energy it takes to charge a capacitor up to voltage V?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is referring to the electrical potential of a charged sphere. The charge will be the same, the radius changes.